# PHP : You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, syntax-error

I am trying to insert data by submitting form and this is the error that I get

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,refno,quantity,imgname, image) 
VALUES('name','Some desc ', '123','123' at line 1
```

following is my sql query

```
$query= mysqli_query($connect,
     "INSERT INTO products(name,desc,refno,quantity) 
      VALUES('$names','$productdesc', '$refno','$quanitity')");
```

Following is the attached screenshot for db 
[image]

if I call `print_r` this is what I get

```
Array
(
    [name] => name
    [refno] => 123
    [quantity] => 123456
    [description] => Some desc 
    [submit] => Add Product
)
```

Comment: DESC is a reserved word,use backticks,  \`desc\`

Comment: Or, better, don't use desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `desc` is a reserved word, you need to put it between backticks to tell MySQL that this is a name and not `desc` that is used in `order by`:

```
$query= mysqli_query($connect,
    "INSERT INTO products(`name`,`desc`,`refno`,`quantity`) 
     VALUES('$names','$productdesc', '$refno','$quanitity')");
```

Your case is a reason that it may be a good idea to always put backticks around such things as column or table names to make sure that even if a word suddenly becomes reserved, your code will not break.

Answer (score 2):

`desc` is a reserved word. If you have control over the schema, I'd advise you to rename the column to a non-reserved word, such as `description`. If this is not possible or feasible, you could escape the column name by surrounding it with back-ticks:

```
$query= mysqli_query($connect,
                     "INSERT INTO products(name,`desc`,refno,quantity) 
                     VALUES('$names','$productdesc', '$refno','$quanitity')");
```

Side note:
Using string manipulation in SQL statements leaves your code vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks. You should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.